# Datatable Plugin data load issue in IE 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using Datatable plugnin. Here it was working fine for 20k data. Now when I am trying to load 40k+ data it is throwing error

> ```
>  0x8007000e - JavaScript runtime error: Not enough storage is available to complete this operation.
> ```

Tried by enabling server side functionality using

> ```
>  "serverSide": true,
> ```

Strangely it is working in Chrome and Firefox.

Please help me out here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're loading the datatable as html, then you could try loading it via ajax instead, as a string array.  That *might* work for awhile.

However, I'd say that you need to paginate your data on the server side, rather than loading it all in at once.

What the message is saying is that you don't have enough memory for the browser to complete the operation.  Each browser is different, and the one you're having troubles with (IE, Safari?) is apparently not good at managing its memory.

Have a look at [datatables.net's example of a server-side implementation](http://datatables.net/examples/server_side/).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but the examples in the link is tough to understand

Comment: Basically, the server side of things will be filtering and paginating the data for you, rather than doing all of this in the browser.  This is so that less data gets returned to the browser and you don't hit the memory limit.  Note that you'll probably hit different limits, depending on the machine used, so your dev machine may be telling you "all's good" when it's not, in reality.